# Bad handler when deploying Lambda function via CloudFormation ZipFile

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I am deploying a Lambda function (Python 3.6) named `lambda_handler` using CloudFormation by specifying the code in-line as described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-code.html).

The Lambda deploys properly, however when testing the function I see a "Bad Handler" exception.

What is the correct way to refer to the handler when passing the `Handler` parameter to Lambda?

Answer (score 5):

Use the handler `index.lambda_handler`. Since there is no deployment package name when submitting in-line code via `ZipFile`, the prefix `index` is used instead.